# После сборки приложения qt, появляется консоль

Tags: qt, qt5, cmake, qt6, windeployqt

Собрал gui приложение через windeployqt.exe, после запуска с exe файла запускается консоль. Использую СMake для сборки приложения.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(untitled1 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui REQUIRED)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        # Gui files
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
        auth_form.h
        auth_form.cpp
        auth_form.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(untitled1
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET untitled1 APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(untitled1 SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(untitled1
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(untitled1 PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Gui)

set_target_properties(untitled1 PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(untitled1)
endif()
```

Comment: Вы б хоть показали что-то о своем приложении, а то так можно долго гадать.

Comment: возможно, в pro файле осталось +console, посмотрите внимательнее

Comment: Использую СMake для сборки приложения.

Comment: @redly ну, показывайте, что вы в CMake понаписали - все экстрасенсы ушли новый сезон Битвы Экстрасенсов снимать

Comment: Добавил........

Comment: По идее, надо во все `add_executable` и `qt_add_executable` добавить ключик (через пробел) WIN32 после первого параметра (target)  https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html

Comment: Добавьте еще *.pro файл. Он важен

Comment: Сработал вариант Александра.

Comment: Раз сработало, то добавлю как ответ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо во все `add_executable` и `qt_add_executable` добавить ключик `WIN32` после первого параметра [(target)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html)